# what other events trigger on link click

Tags: javascript, events

I want to initiate cart submission automatically. I have

```
<a href="javascript:alert('javascript');" onclick="alert('onclick')" class="simpleCart_checkout hudbtn primary right">Checkout</a>
```

And javascript

```
<script>
$('.simpleCart_checkout').trigger('click');
</script>
```

So I get alert `click` on page load but not `javascript` alert and simple cart not submitting data. So what more do I need to trigger so it will fully imitate link click?

Thanks

PS
When I click mouse on Checkout simplecart submits data to another page with cart items etc. But if I try imitate click  alert happen only but not cart submission.

Comment: the order of location the same as in the description, so after <a>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing is 1st. Remove all the inline silliness from the DOM element:

```
<a href="#" class="simpleCart_checkout hudbtn primary right">Checkout</a>
```

Second. If you are going to use jQuery, use jQuery!

```
<script>
$('.simpleCart_checkout').on('click', function() {
     alert("onclick");
     return false;
}).trigger('click');
</script>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/dY26m/

Comment: Well, click works on my example too but problem is simplecart doesn't do nothing if I do as mine or your example

Comment: @OleksandrKhavdiy "doesn't do nothing"? ummmm that is a double negative, so I have to ask: What **does** it do?

Comment: When I click mouse on Checkout simplecart submits data to another page with cart items etc. But if I try something like you or I wrote, happen alert only but not cart submission.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to imitate a real click on anchors using `.trigger()`; it will only perform the default behaviour if a user clicks on it.

The `.trigger('click')` will only run the `onclick` handlers.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, anything like

```
javascript:alert('');
```

should not be used.and when I copy paste the code, I see both the alerts on clicking. I gree with the way neal has posted. that is how you do it. Remember when you mix javascript with html it all becomes a mess.

You will notice this but firing a click event does not allow redirction to a new page. That means actually you cannot navigate to a new page, by triggering click on a link.
Since javascript:alert(''); is in href attribute, it will not work.

Triggers are meant to fire events that are caught. Not actual clicks.

Comment: yes, if I click I see that too, but if I try to trigger it no luck